# extern declaration 2D array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

If I define a simple array :

```
int tableint[][2] = {
      {1,  2},
      {2,  4},
      {3,  9},
      {4, 16},
      {5, 25}
};
```

and code in the very same file as :

```
printf("Value = %d\n",sizeof(tableint));
printf("Value = %d\n",sizeof(tableint[0]));
printf("Num of rows = %d\n",sizeof(tableint)/sizeof(tableint[0]));
```

Output is as expected:

```
Value = 40
Value = 8
Num of rows = 5
```

But if I move the same 'tableint' 2D array in a separate file and retain above mentioned print statements in the previous main file but just adding an extern as follows:

```
extern int tableint[][2];
```

I get an error in the following line:

```
printf("Value = %d\n",sizeof(tableint));
```

as : **invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'int[][2]'**

I am curious to know why it worked when the 2D array was there within the same file and not when I moved it into another file?

And, the error gets resolved if I define the extern as:

```
extern int tableint[5][2];
```

Is there any way where I don't need to mention the number of rows in extern here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An array declared in this fashion - with `[]` in the declaration - will have complete type if and only if the declaration includes an initializer. Without an initializer the type is incomplete.

That's your difference that made it work in the first case.

If you really need to declare it as `extern`, then you have no choice but to specify all sizes explicitly, as long as you require this `sizeof` technique to work (or as long as you want to see the array size as a *constant expression*).

If you don't care about being able to use that `sizeof` trick and if you'd be happy with seeing the array size as run-time value, then you could export it from that "separate file" as another variable or as function.

Comment: There are other options , e.g. `extern tableint[][2];` plus some function which gets the length

Comment: @M.M.: Yes, if the OP doesn't mind losing the ability to see the size as *constant expression*.

Answer (score 3):

This is because C source files are treated as separate, individual *translation units*, than can be compiled independent to each other (for instance with `gcc -c ...`). The information stored in some unit is not accesssible to another one until linkage phase is concerned.

With that said, the spec is clear that you cannot take `sizeof` operator for an incomplete type, as N1570 6.5.3.4/1 *The sizeof and _Alignof operators* says:

> The `sizeof` operator shall not be applied to an expression that has
>   function type or an incomplete type, to the parenthesized name of such
>   a type, or to an expression that designates a bit-field member.